# how to get the dynamic PID of a windows service and then kill it?

Tags: cmd

I have an own windows service. I want to get the PID of the service and then kill it in the cmd.

Which command could do this for me?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use `tasklist` to enumerate the processes:

```
@echo off

for /f "tokens=2" %%p in ('tasklist /fi "imagename eq your_svc.exe" /nh') do (
  set PID=%%p
)
```

and then kill the process via `taskkill`:

```
taskkill /pid %PID%
```