# Get the PID of a Windows service by the name of the service

Tags: windows, batch-file, service, cmd, pid

Is there a way of getting the PID of a windows service with a command in a batch script by just knowing the name of the service?

Comment: This doesn't work for you? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17472903/how-to-get-the-dynamic-pid-of-a-windows-service-and-then-kill-it

Comment: No this is not what I want.That code will find the PID by the .exe file not by the name of the service.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Try the following code:

```
FOR /F "tokens=3" %%A IN ('sc queryex %serviceName% ^| findstr PID') DO (SET pid=%%A)
 IF "!pid!" NEQ "0" (
  taskkill /F /PID !pid!
 )
```

Comment: Beware that many services may share the same PID.  Try `for /f "tokens=3" %A in ('sc queryex w32time ^| find "PID"') do wmic service where "ProcessID=%A" get caption,name,processid /value` from a cmd prompt.

Comment: The OP didn't ask for code to kill the service, Surely in that case you would just use sc.exe to stop it rather than directly kill the process, which could host multiple services. You could also use something like `tasklist /svc /fi "services eq %serviceName%" /fo list` to get the PID plus a list of all services hosted by the process.

Comment: It seems that `taskkill /F /PID !pid!` should be `taskkill /F /PID %pid%`

Comment: @CodenameK - I agree. I edited the answer but it appears that my edit was rejected.

Answer (score 16):

It's much easier to just do `taskkill /f /fi "SERVICES eq <service_short_name>"`

Answer (score 3):

```
@echo off

for /f "tokens= delims=" %%# in ('
  wmic service where "name='Service'" get ProcessId /format:value
') do (
  for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%$ in ("%%#") do set "%%$"
)

taskkill /pid %ProcessId% /f
```